# AES 256 Decryption in c#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, aes

I am new to asp.net webapi and developing an interface app to external system. The webapi body gets the encrypted JSON string (AES256) from external system and they provide the secret key as well.

Kindly help

Comment: i have  decrypted using AES , but it is showing additional encrypted fields

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.